# how to bind data from a model to a text-box instead of a list-box

Tags: c#, mysql, data-modeling

i get data from my database through means of dapper and a data model i then bind that data to a list box and it all works fine but now i want to bind that data to a text-box. previously i would just get the data bind it to a hidden list-box and then get that data from the list box but i now want to learn how to do this correctly.

```
          //this is my current workaround.
        textBox1.Text = description.GetItemText(description.SelectedItem);
```

i have also tried to bind the load-inventory to text-box but that doesn't work.

```
        //datamodel prop
        description.DataSource = loadinventory;

        //datamodel full prop
        description.DisplayMember = "ItemDescription";

       textBox1.DataBindings.Clear(); 
       textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("text", loadinventory, 
       "ItemDescription"));
```

this worked perfect.

```
        textBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("text", loadinventory, 
        "ItemDescription"));
```

i want to pull data from my database using data-models and dapper to my text-box and other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("text", loadinventory, "ItemDescription");
```

Some more details https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: +  $exception {"This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.\r\nParameter name: binding"} System.ArgumentException

Comment: i get that error. i tried to clear the binding from text box then run the given code but nothing happens.

Comment: i tried this textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("text", loadinventory, "ItemDescription"));

Comment: no it all runs fine but the box is just empty. when i do a break it shows that the values are actually being loaded but now i this it just has something to do with the displaying of the data

Comment: Please refresh the textbox.

Comment: worked perfect please see updated code. did i do the refresh correctly tho lol.

Comment: Hi, not sure if i need to open a new tread for this but is there a way to bind this to a variable like "string description" instead of a textbox?

Comment: not directly strings don't have a datasource, but you can bind it to a for this case declared textbox and copy the text into a string variable. if you need a string array , you have to go over the  table rows in a loop and add an elements to the array.

Comment: yes that's my current work around i bind it to a hidden text-box its just the image path tho which i don't use much in the software anyways. was hoping to eliminate the extra text-box tho but o well